# Edit using SharePoint designer in SP 2010 vs 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 and need to edit a site in SharePoint designer. In SharePoint 2010 there was an icon where I could do this but it seems to be gone in 2013. Anyone know what to do?